# Comparing Session Variable to a String C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, variables

```
string currentUser;
string currentPassword;
string getUserName;
string getPassword;

getUserName = Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]);
getPassword = Convert.ToString(Session["Password"]);

currentUser = Convert.ToString(txtUserNameLogIn.Text);
currentPassword = Convert.ToString(txtPasswordLogin.Text);

if ((currentUser == getUserName ) && (currentPassword == getPassword)) {
    currentUser = Convert.ToString(Session["CurrentUser"]);
    currentPassword = Convert.ToString(Session["CurrentPassword"]);
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
} else {
    lblResult.Text = "Invalid Password";

}
```

I have 3 pages. First one for registration, that saves UserName and Password so a Session and then I have login page that should take the UserName and Password sessions and compare them to the current user input on this page. So far I'm not getting any responses.

Edit: The username and password that I put in on previous page gets stored in a Session Variable called "UserName", the person gets re-directed to login page and I simply want to compare what user types in with the Session Variable from previous page and if it's correct, store that information in new Session Variable and re-direct user to home page.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, I don't think you should be storing username and password in the session

Comment: First off do not save a users password in plain/clear text, ever, in any form. Second, do not misuse session like this. There are plenty of *good* authentication and authorization frameworks out there that you can use free of charge and ready to go. Do your research and use one of those so your site is not just another trove of user information ready to be exploited by the first hacker that comes across it.

Comment: It's just for a programming coursework, we are only learning and understanding how this works.

Comment: your first 2 lines retrieve the data from the session, then you check if the inputs `current...`are equal to that, then you get the sessions stuff AGAIN out of the session and set your `current....`(which are euqal to them) to them again- WHY?

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a statement. The code you have, while strange and non-optimal, appears like it would work so all I can suggest is providing more context.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I done that so I could use it on my Home Page. The first sessions compare of the sessions are equal to user input.

Comment: @KevinKalitowski In simplest form. The username and password that I put in on previous page gets stored in a Session Variable called "UserName", the person gets re-directed to login page and I simply want to compare what user types in with the Session Variable from previous page and if it's correct, store that information in new Session Variable and re-direct user to home page.

Comment: @MrDarkness96 my comment doesn't change. What you have appears fine. With the little context I have, I think it should work. That leads me to believe there is some piece of information that I do not have that would be critical to solving the issue. I would put a breakpoint on the `if` line and look at the runtime values. You should easily be able to see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things here working under the assumption this is a test project and you know Session is not the correct place to store plaintext credentials. Take a look at [SimpleMembership](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates) for a cleaner approach.

That out of the way I created two extension classes. The first takes care of string security, and the second takes care of Session. You can take this a step further and create constants for the keys or even a SessionUser object. In terms of comparison I just combined both username+password so the logic is short.

```
 public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Encrypt(this string plainText)
    {
        // Replace with your encryption impl
        return plainText;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(this string hiddenText)
    {
        // Replace with your decryption impl 
        return hiddenText;
    }
}

public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this HttpSessionState sessionState, string key, T value)
    {
        sessionState[key] = value;
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this HttpSessionState sessionState, string key) where T : class
    {
        return (T)sessionState[key];
    }
}

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Set("UserName", "something");
        Session.Set("Password", "something".Encrypt());

        var username = Session.Get<string>("UserName");
        var password = Session.Get<string>("Password").Decrypt();

        var savedUser = $"{username}{password}";
        var currentUser = $"somethingsomething";

        if (currentUser.Equals(savedUser, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```